# How can I assert dynamic URLs in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

We are using AngularJS to develop our website in that our URLs are changing dynamically, so I need to change URLs for every time. How can I assert those dynamic changes in protractor?

Comment: expose the url path's thru some variable

Comment: What have you tried so far? $routeParams will expose url routes... Assuming you are using routing.... And assuming that `$routeParams` is injected into your controller... Beginning to see why it's important to add as much information to questions as possible? :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am new to this Protractor, I have used below assertion, but it is not working as expected.    **expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(baseurl+'/cli/dashboard?scopeId=57d67c52f3d82000079b75c9');**    in this the scopeId thing is changing randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toContain` jasmine selector to verify string contains in URl.

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(baseurl+'/cli/dashboard‌​?scopeId=')
```

if the scope id is stored in any `$scope` variable, then you can use `evaluate()` method in protractor to get the value of any scope variable from the angular page.

Comment: Glad it worked!! Make sure you accept the answer to make this topic closed!! Thanks.